# Network setting when making a VM

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

My group and I are making a VM for our big project and we have a have a problem with network settings. We are watching LinusTechTips video "1 CPU 2 Gamers" and in the network settings he has the option "Setup Bridge" and we don't have that. We can't start the Array without it enabled and my only thought is that we are connected to the school's network and something is being blocked from Setup Bridge from popping up. Is there a way I can make it pop up or is the school network really the problem?

PLEASE ANSWER!

Comment: Link to the video? How can we know what you are talking about?

Comment: It might help if you mentioned what the host OS is, what the guest OS is, what virtualization software you're using, and so on.  If you're in school, why not ask the support person in the lab?  Is your homework late or something?